# How can I solve problems iteratively in CVXPY?

Tags: cvxpy

I want to solve a problem, then use that problem's variables in another problem's constraints, solve it, use the second problem's variables in a third problem's constraints, and so on until the distance between the nth and the (n-1)-th variables is small enough.

Comment: I don't think cvxpy is designed to do this. It seems more straightforward to just solve cxvpy problems iteratively?

Comment: And how would I go about doing that? I'm a beginner so I know almost nothing about this stuff.

Comment: I think you described it in your question :) Solve the first problem -> get the solution -> use it as a constraint for the second problem -> Solve the second problem -> keep going like this until your done. If you want more help, I think you'll need to explain your problem more: try to be unambiguous or use an example.